# trying to create an hq svg, but also remove the black space top and bottom of image

Tags: inkscape, svg, black

im trying to create an hq svg, but also remove the black space top and bottom of image.

im having difficulties, ive tried vectormagic, picsvg, now i am trying to use
inkscape, but im not even sure if its possible in ink scape, i can create the svg no problems, but removing the black and top and bottom is a pin, as black is part of the image detail. so i need to somehow create thin black line border around the image instead of the large black space.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMSnK.jpg

my plan was to burn it onto wood with a laser

thanks

dave

Comment: The image is reversed out. Can't you just invert it?  Then draw a rectangle around it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility with Inkscape

1. In the example below, I did a Trace Bitmap in Inkscape, using the "invert" option.
2. Then I selected the drawing, and set the fill to white (this will make it disappear temporarily)
3. Then I added a thick black outer stroke, with rounded joins

[image]

4. With the Bézier tool, I redrew some of the black areas that are missing, such as the black of the Darth Vader mask. and the area around the head of the character just above R2D2, and sent those to the bottom of the layer stack.
5. Then I drew a thin rectangle around everything

[image]

Comment: wow that is amazing :) do you have the full size artwork you can send ?

Comment: i tried duplicating that but could not get join type selected

Comment: which mode did you use in trace bitmap ?

Comment: @alienkidmj12 - just use the default settings, but choose the "invert" option. [See example](https://imgur.com/b59xZLF).  Sorry I didn't save it, also we don't give out free artwork here anyway as it's frowned upon.

Comment: ive managed to get to the point where i need to use Bézier tool, i guess whats to make lines, so then i can use the fill option ?

Comment: @alienkidmj12 - yes make shapes with the Bézier tool, fill them, then move to the bottom of the layer stack.